# Why is the turtle in python not working when I import it?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here's my code

```
Import turtle

t = turtle.pen()

t.forward(50)
```

And this is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
File "<pyshell#4>", Line 1, in <module>
t.forward(50)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'forward'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turtle.pen is used to set/get pen attributes of turtle but not to draw(see help(turtle.pen) for more info), in order to draw something you need to get Turtle object as follow:

```
import turtle
tur=turtle.Turtle();
tur.forward(50);
```

Answer (score -1):

the right answer is to capitalize "P", in "pen"

Comment: Could elaborate your answer with explanation on what is the difference between `Pen` and `pen` and why the former is correct and the latter not? To make your answer really quality you can support it with some links and quotes from official docs